# adding to database error

Tags: java, swing

I've create a database and I'm adding records from GUI.
I also created a delete button.
Once I delete a record and try to add a new one it gives me this error

```
java.sql.SQLException: 
Incorrect integervalue:'javax.swing.JTextField[jTextField16,413,390,19x28,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignmentX=0.0,alignme'
for column path at row1
```

Comment: My bad forgot to change Integer.parseInt to my code.
Solved it

Answer (score 2):

Your database is excpecting an integer, it's getting a string instead.
You are probably doing

```
textField.toString();
```

instead of

```
Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
```